# Creating Diagonals in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to convert my columns to diagonals using SAS.

For example

D C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
J 11 00 14 15 20
F 00 13 16 00 30
M 00 00 18 19 00
A 00 00 00 98 50
S 00 00 00 00 41

Want this converted to

D N1 N2 N3 N4 N5
J 11 00 14 15 20
F 13 16 00 30
M 18 19 00
A 98 50
M 41

Can anyone tell or help me with this?

Comment: Your question is unclear; how do you get from your input data to output data? What have you already tried?

Comment: I have tried proc transpose. The problems is that I do have zeros as values and this causes the diagonals to shift incorrectly. I create the input using data, the output needs to be in a triangle format. With the first column being the first diagonal and the last column being the last diagonal I do have 100 or more columns. This was a simplified version of what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update base on new info:  This just uses an array to shift the values starting from the diagonal to the left.  Not dependent of on values in the lower triangle.

```
data havethis;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   input D:$1. C1-C5;
   cards;
D C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
J 11 00 14 15 20
F 00 13 16 00 30
M 00 00 18 19 00
A 00 00 00 98 50
S 00 00 00 00 41
;;;;
   run;
data want;
   set havethis;
   array c[*] c:;
   array N[&sysnobs];
   j = 0;
   do i = _n_ to dim(c);
      j + 1;
      n[j] = c[i];
      end;
   drop j i;
   run;
```

[image]

This method use two transposes (flip/flop), it assumes only zeros are on the off diagonal (better if they were missing) and missing is what you get as result.  I like this method because you don't have to know anything, like how many.

```
data havethis;
   input D:$1. C1 C2 C3;
   format c: z2.;
   cards;
J 11 12 14
M 00 13 15
A 00 00 16
;;;;
   run;
proc transpose data=havethis out=wantthis(drop=_name_ where=(col1 ne 0));
   by D notsorted;
   run;
proc transpose data=wantthis out=whatthismore(drop=_name_) prefix=N;
   by d notsorted;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. One problem is that do indeed have zeros as values in between. Due to this the diagonals are not correct, have been trying to fix it (using this code) but no such luck. Lets say instead of 12 it was 0 how would the code look like then?

Comment: Show example of the new scenario.

Comment: I have updated my original question. Struggling a bit since I have never used stackoverflow. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to change the code a bit since it didn't like using &sysnobs. Not sure why. Replaced it with Proc Sql noprint;
 Select count(*)
  Into :NObs
 From Test1;
Quit; One last question. How can i use the code and only keep the new columns created without hardcoding For example I don't want to do this. Keep N1-N200. Rather Do N1-N[&Nobs]. no specifying the last column created with the number 200 for example (or N1 if I can avoid that).

Comment: keep N:;  Or keep N1-N&nobs;

Comment: Used keep N:; . Thanks for all your help. Going to ask a new question.... If you want up to helping some more...